# I created a html form and using php I want to get the data and post it on another page inside a container

Tags: php, html, forms, posting

I'm having a hard time wrapping my idea into text so basically this is how  I want to do this.

I have form.html once completed it tells the user thanks for filling out and goes back to the home page. then the data taken using php posts the data to gallery.html where their pic and info are posted.

How do I go about accomplishing this? How do I post it to a specific location in gallery.html?
You don't need to all my work its just I cant seem to find it on here or anywhere else it might be really simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to setup a simple database to store the data in, making sure that you are using safe practices for data insertion into the database. And then on the gallery page you can call a specific id from the url to display the proper data. Like gallery.php?profile=5

On the gallery.php page it would query the database looking for id #5 and get all the data out of it the database and echo it on the page.

Answer (score 1):

**Form.html**

- User fills in the form
- User clicks submit
- Form data will go for processing to a page, say `thanks.php`

**Thanks.php**

- Collect form data
- Store it in database
- Redirect to homepage.php after successful insertion

**Homepage.php**

- Show message saying 'Thank you for filling out the form'
- Give a link in this page to view the details of user
- Something like this `<a href=gallery.php?rowid=<?php echo <insert primary column value here from database>?">View Profile</a>`

**Gallery.php**

- Grab the id using $_GET `$rowid = $_GET['rowid'];`
- Use `$rowid` in `WHERE` clause of your database query `$q = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <primary key column name> = '".$rowid."'";`
- Use the returned set to show that particular user's data.

Comment: Explain the downvote please. Let me know what I did wrong here

Comment: 2nd answer with SQL injection in a row.

Comment: Oh cmon, This is workflow example. This is what the OP asked for. I'm afraid you're nitpicking here

Comment: Your rock thank you i wouldnt of guessed using a database i guess

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong in understanding how php works , Here are the mistakes that I could identify in your posting ,

your calling a webpage as gallery.html , but without .php extension , Apache wont call php interpreter when it receives a request , so to accomplish this you need to rename this to gallery.php .

to accomplish your task

here is the approach

1 > in your form.html page set attribute of form tag action=store.php method = post

2 >  within store.php connect to mysql database and store all data in mysql data base , 
after successfully storing data display a thank you message and redirect to home page

3 > in your gallery.php file based on the requested id display the profile

NOTE : - you need to design your database in mysql with a table and column to store profile details

Comment: sorry ya im low on time its a project formyself and i wanted to get it out ive only barely read a book on it to be honest thank you for your help